# Two JS files attached to one module

Tags: 7, javascript

Alright, so I have two files which should be added to a module. This is the way I do it:

```
$form['display']['#attached'] = array(
    'js' => array(
      array('data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test_module') . '/js/test_module.js'),
      array('data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test_module') . '/js/common.js'),
    ),
  );
```

Now my test_module.js file looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.test_module = {
  attach: function(context) {
    console.log(Drupal.settings);
  }
}});
```

And js works fine because I get data from Drupal.settings object. However, the second one is totaly the same and console.log does not work. Here's how it looks:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.test_module = {
      attach: function(context) {
        console.log("test data");
      }
    }});
```

Why the second file does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't duplicate the attach function.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.test_module = {
  attach: function(context) {
    console.log(Drupal.settings);
  }
}})(jQuery);
```

If you have used this for 1st JS

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.test_module_2 = {
  attach: function(context) {
    console.log("test data");
  }
}})(jQuery);
```

Then you can use this for 2nd JS as the attach function should be used only once

Comment: Just to be clear, if the two functions have the same name, you end up with just one, because one replaces the other.

Comment: So how this second file should look like? I've tried many different approaches but none of them work. :(

Comment: If the concern is about working, it should work. Just try my example. Let me know if there is any issue!

Comment: Ok, so all it was about this end of file which you included }})(jQuery); Thank you for support.

Answer (score 1):

You are duplicating the attach function here.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.test_module = {
  attach: function(context) {
    console.log(Drupal.settings);
  }
}})(jQuery);
```

This should be used only once. I mean in Drupal.behaviors.test_module only one function can be attached to be called at document.ready